# Apply sign function to a column that contains NaN values

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a column that contains both valid numbers as well as NaN. I want to apply sign function on its values and keep the result in a new column.

When I use `np.sign` as follows, it fails saying: `{TypeError} unorderable types for comparison`.

```
df['new_column'] = np.sign(df['column'])
```

Note that I cannot replace `NaN` with 0 or something beforehand. In my case if it is a NaN, its sign should be NaN as well.

Comment: Needs sample data. This works perfectly fine for something like `df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [1, 2, 3, np.nan]})`

Comment: @BigBen it fails with exact error for `np.sign(df['column'].astype('object')`; which OP might need to be looking at.

Comment: Works for me though `test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(np.random.randint(-5,5,50))})
na_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.NaN]*4})
test_df = pd.concat([test_df,na_df],axis=0)` and then `np.sign(test_df['a'])`

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Could you post some data to reproduce the problem?
For example: dtype, values, and what kind of "NaN" you are using.

The problem can be anywhere, have a look here:

**As you can see, no problem with np.nan:**

```
np.sign([53,54,512,3,np.nan])
Out[16]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1., nan])
```

**But pd.NA does not work (another exception than in your case):**

```
np.sign([53,54,512,3,pd.NA])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gamer\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3251, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-14-22d6e4b28023>", line 1, in <module>
np.sign([53,54,512,3,pd.NA])
File "pandas\_libs\missing.pyx", line 382, in 
pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Some data would be useful.